# Android Spinner setOnItemSelectedListener does not fire however it shows correct values from API

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, spinner

I have problem with Spinner. I download data from API using Volley and put it into Spinner. I can see all items that I get from API. However I can not select it, also spinner setOnItemSelectedListener does not fire (no logs, no toasts).
Logs from getDataFromAPI() works great, all data is correctly downloaded from source.

You can see code below.

Thanks for help.

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.plantapp.Model.WeatherStation;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StationUser extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner stationUserSpinnerStation, stationUserSpinnerConfirm;

    private String IMGW_URL = "https://danepubliczne.imgw.pl/api/data/synop";
    private ArrayList<WeatherStation> WeatherList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> StationList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RequestQueue mQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_station_user);

        stationUserSpinnerStation = findViewById(R.id.stationUserSpinnerStation);

        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        getDataFromAPI();

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, StationList);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        stationUserSpinnerStation.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        stationUserSpinnerStation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String spinnerValue = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                stationUserSpinnerStation.setSelection(position);
                Log.d("saodjawduiaw", spinnerValue + " " + position + " " + id + "\n\n");
                Toast.makeText(StationUser.this,
                        "Selected item" + spinnerValue,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast.makeText(StationUser.this,
                        "Selected item",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    private void getDataFromAPI() {
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, IMGW_URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject station = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String stacja = station.getString("stacja");
                                double temperatura = station.getDouble("temperatura");
                                double suma_opadu = station.getDouble("suma_opadu");
                                WeatherStation tempstation = new WeatherStation(stacja, temperatura, suma_opadu);
                                WeatherList.add(tempstation);
                                StationList.add(stacja);
                                Log.d("info", stacja + " " + temperatura + " " + suma_opadu + "\n\n");
                                Log.d("stacja", tempstation.getStation() + tempstation.getTemperature() + tempstation.getRainfall());
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this, define **arrayadapter** as global variable then initialize **arrayadapter** inside **onCreate** method, then Call **arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** inside **onResponse** method

```
public class StationUser extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Spinner stationUserSpinnerStation, stationUserSpinnerConfirm;
    private String IMGW_URL = "https://danepubliczne.imgw.pl/api/data/synop";
    private ArrayList<WeatherStation> WeatherList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> StationList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        stationUserSpinnerStation = findViewById(R.id.stationUserSpinnerStation);

        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        getDataFromAPI();

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, StationList);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        stationUserSpinnerStation.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        stationUserSpinnerStation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String spinnerValue = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                stationUserSpinnerStation.setSelection(position);
                Log.d("saodjawduiaw", spinnerValue + " " + position + " " + id + "\n\n");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Selected item" + spinnerValue,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Selected item",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    private void getDataFromAPI() {
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, IMGW_URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject station = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String stacja = station.getString("stacja");
                                double temperatura = station.getDouble("temperatura");
                                double suma_opadu = station.getDouble("suma_opadu");
                                WeatherStation tempstation = new WeatherStation(stacja, temperatura, suma_opadu);
                                WeatherList.add(tempstation);
                                StationList.add(stacja);
                                Log.d("info", stacja + " " + temperatura + " " + suma_opadu + "\n\n");
                                Log.d("stacja", tempstation.getData1() + tempstation.getData2() + tempstation.getData3());

                                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mQueue.add(request);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Your solution worked, and I got what I wanted. However I can say that I deal with this problem with two simple lines StationList.add("Default Value"); stationUserSpinnerStation.setSelection(0);